# Linux, 50% ОЗУ занимает buff/cache

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование

Здравствуйте, вот начал разбираться с системным администратированием, арендовал VPS Centos 7 x64, установил туда apache/nginx/php/mysql и тд. для работы сайта (до этого использовал хостинг), запустил, все работает.

Но в таблице top на сколько я вижу, ~500 мб из 1гб ОЗУ приходится на buff/cache. Я не очень опытен в этом, не знаю как работает эта кэш система, и нужна ли вообще она, просто хотел бы узнать у вас нормально ли это, или же стоит установить лимиты и делать  чистку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё нормально. Ядро линукса само управляет этими вещами. А без особой надобности и тем более не знания в это лучше не вмешиваться.

Comment: http://linuxatemyram.ru/

Comment: вопрос: вот у меня мотор что-то быстро крутиться и тарахтит, что не так и как самому вертеть его с нужной скоростью? - ответ ходи пешком или окунись в глубины не изведанного https://www.kernel.org/doc/